# Logical question

Tags: logic

Let P and Q be two propositions
I was wondering if
$P\Rightarrow Q$ is the equivalent of "P then Q"
I think it's not the case but i'm not sure 
and i need a counter example

Comment: $P \Rightarrow Q$ iff $P \rightarrow Q$ is a tautology

Comment: So if isn't a tautology i can't claim that is equivalent to P then Q

Comment: If "P then Q" is not a tautology, then is not equivalent to $P \Rightarrow Q$. Remember that $P \Rightarrow Q$ (i. e. "P implies Q") is always true no matter what P and Q are. This is different than $P \rightarrow Q$ which is false when P is true but Q is false

Comment: See [Conditional (connective)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Common_logical_connectives): the natural language expression: "if..., then..." is formalized with the *conditional connective* (also called: *material implication*) usually simbolized with $\to$ or $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: @L.Salvetti "Remember that P⇒Q (i. e. "P implies Q") is always true no matter what P and Q are." Oh good-oh! I hereby announce that the consistency of Peano Arithmetic implies that P $\neq$ NP. Can I claim my million dollars?